# I need a transcendental meromorphic function which omits zero and the kth derivative of the function omits some some non-constant small function

Tags: complex-analysis

Can some construct a tranecendental meromorphic function f in complex plane which omits a single value and its kth derivative omits small function of f.

Comment: What is your definition of "small function of f" ?

Comment: g is said to be small function of f if T(r,g)=o(T(r,f))  as r tends to infinity possibly outside of set of finite linear measure